# Render Model retrieved through ajax with displayattribute

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display the Model using ajax call, but I am stuck on how I can read the Model display attribute value

here what I tried so far

Controller method

```
[AjaxOnly]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VehicleDetails()
{
     var details = db.Vehicles.Where(m=>m.RentById = User.Id);
     return Json(new {vehicles = details});
}
```

Model Content

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    [Display(Name="Code",typeof(ResourceType=Resources.Translation))]
    public string Code{get; set;}
    [Display(Name="PlateNumber",typeof(ResourceType=Resources.Translation))]
    public string PlateNumber{get; set;}
    [Display(Name="Model",typeof(ResourceType=Resources.Translation))]
    public int Model{get; set;}
}
```

View content

```
<div id="vehicle"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url:'@Url.Action("VehicleDetails","Company")';
           type: 'post',
           success: function(result){
               for(var detail in result.vehicles){
                    // how to access the Code display attribute value?
               }
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show your `VehicleDetails()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke i added it

Comment: Your method is only returning your model (i.e. the value of its properties, not the value of any `DisplayAttribute`).

Comment: @StephenMuecke if i returned the result as PartialView and I used LabelFor, the display attribute will be retrieved based on the language, but i want to display the result as ajax in order to avoid the time taken by the method to retrieve the details

Comment: @mah you can return the partialview as json result, then your code will be $('#vehicle').html(result);

Comment: The client can't read values if your controller doesn't send them :). Either (a) return a partial view and update the DOM or (b) initially render the `LabelFor()` elements inside (say) a hidden div with `id` attributes so you can retrieve them inside the `success` callback or (c) add the values to the `JsonResult`